# Umbraco - Edit a custiom data type

Tags: umbraco

I want to modify an existing custom data type in Umbraco. I tried to look for an option but somehow I can't see the Edit option in context. Does anyone have an idea about this ?

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: What kind of data type is it? Are you looking for the section in Umbraco where you can edit data types?

Answer (score 1):

To create your own Data Type click right on the Data Types folder in the Developer section of the Umbraco Admin page select create and type in the name you want to call it.

A panel will then be displayed where you can choose which data type you want in the Property editor.

When you press the save button the settings relevant to the data type you have chosen will be displayed. They will also always then show up when you select that data type in the data types tree.

These are the only data type settings you can change in the Umbraco Admin section I know of.